# Flex: AdvancedDataGridColumn tooltip interference

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, tooltip, advanceddatagrid

The [`AdvancedDataGridColumn`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/advancedDataGridClasses/AdvancedDataGridColumn.html) has a property `showDataTips`. If this is set to `true` then each cell in the `AdvancedDataGridColumn` will show a toolTip on `rollOver`. There is just one problem, the toolTip covers the entire cell.

This is a problem, because the cell has a custom `contextMenu`. Right clicking the toolTip will bring up the default menu. Is there a way to click through the toolTip or provide a `yOffset` so that the tooltip appears below the cell?

Comment: I was also facing the same issue and didn't finded any solution. 
so i tried this and it's working really fine for me. :)

(http://blogs.adobe.com/jgarnett/2011/04/04/displaying-extremely-large-strings-in-a-flex-datagridcolumn/)

i was doing this for displaying lengthy comments in datagrid.

Comment: Here's how you position your custom tooltip: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7ff6.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf60d65-7fef

Comment: @ethrbunny The tooltip for the AdvancedDataGrid defaults to fill the cell. I cannot attach an `ROLL_OVER`/`ROLL_OUT` listener to an AdvancedDataGridColumn. I do not want to add the listener to the whole grid, because only certain columns should display the custom tooltip.

Comment: Right. You need to define a custom one and attach it to the whole thing. Then filter which to show custom and which to show default in the handler.